# How to update the first item in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to get my head around ng-repeat and sort! I have a list of JSON objects as follows:

Current user list:
[{user: abc, name: ABC},{user: xzy, name: XZY}]

I've got an ng-repeat that iterates the list to display the user details. This all works, however, I want the first item in the list to be that of the logged in user. In this case user xzy is the logged in user so that person should display first.

Any help is appreciated.

J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom `orderBy` function and put the current user first, ex:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy: currentUser"></div>
```

And the function

```
$scope.currentUser = function(user) {
    if (user.user == $scope.currentUserName) return 0
    else return 1;
}
```

Where `$scope.currentUserName` holds the user name of the currently logged in user.

Comment: Your solution looks elegant. It will return the currentUserName first. However, can you decide the order of all the other items with this method? Can an arbitrary sorting be included, for all the other item, in the $scope.currentUser function? If so, it would be a more angular-oriented solution than mine, which does the sorting in the controller with common javascript

Comment: @Manube -- You can absolutely sort other items in the function, or make another sort function. `orderBy` takes an array of args, so you could do `orderBy: [currentUser, nextSort, nextNextSort, n, n..]`

Comment: well your solution is then more angular-oriented, as it uses a filter, well done